# Using Google Calendar API, is there a way to get and store the attendees response?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am trying to integrate an chat web-app with Google Calendar API. The chat app consist of streams/channels, to which many users are subscribed to.

If an admin creates a shared event in a stream (maybe a meeting or a discussion), it notifies all the subscribers of that stream.

Is it possible, and if yes how, to get the feedback response of the subscribers back to organiser of event, indicating "Attending/Interested" status of the subscribers? This can be something like Facebook events, where users can click "Interested" and that gets counted.

Answer (score 0):

When you have checked the documentation, the Calendar API provides different flavors of event resources, more information can be found in [About events](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#top_of_page).

From the [Resource representations](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource-representations):

> ```
> {
>   "kind": "calendar#event",
>   "etag": etag,
>   "id": string,
>   "status": string,
>   "htmlLink": string,
>   "created": datetime,
>   "updated": datetime,
>   "summary": string,
>   "description": string,
>   "location": string,
>   "colorId": string,
>   "creator": {
>     "id": string,
>     "email": string,
>     "displayName": string,
>     "self": boolean
>   },
>   "organizer": {
>     "id": string,
>     "email": string,
>     "displayName": string,
>     "self": boolean
>   },
>   "start": {
>     "date": date,
>     "dateTime": datetime,
>     "timeZone": string
>   },
>   "end": {
>     "date": date,
>     "dateTime": datetime,
>     "timeZone": string
>   },
>   "endTimeUnspecified": boolean,
>   "recurrence": [
>     string
>   ],
>   "recurringEventId": string,
>   "originalStartTime": {
>     "date": date,
>     "dateTime": datetime,
>     "timeZone": string
>   },
>   "transparency": string,
>   "visibility": string,
>   "iCalUID": string,
>   "sequence": integer,
>   "attendees": [
>     {
>       "id": string,
>       "email": string,
>       "displayName": string,
>       "organizer": boolean,
>       "self": boolean,
>       "resource": boolean,
>       "optional": boolean,
>       "responseStatus": string,
>       "comment": string,
>       "additionalGuests": integer
>     }
>   ],
>   "attendeesOmitted": boolean,
>   "extendedProperties": {
>     "private": {
>       (key): string
>     },
>     "shared": {
>       (key): string
>     }
>   },
>   "hangoutLink": string,
>   "conferenceData": {
>     "createRequest": {
>       "requestId": string,
>       "conferenceSolutionKey": {
>         "type": string
>       },
>       "status": {
>         "statusCode": string
>       }
>     },
>     "entryPoints": [
>       {
>         "entryPointType": string,
>         "uri": string,
>         "label": string,
>         "pin": string,
>         "accessCode": string,
>         "meetingCode": string,
>         "passcode": string,
>         "password": string
>       }
>     ],
>     "conferenceSolution": {
>       "key": {
>         "type": string
>       },
>       "name": string,
>       "iconUri": string
>     },
>     "conferenceId": string,
>     "signature": string,
>     "notes": string,
>     "gadget": {
>     "type": string,
>     "title": string,
>     "link": string,
>     "iconLink": string,
>     "width": integer,
>     "height": integer,
>     "display": string,
>     "preferences": {
>       (key): string
>     }
>   },
>   "anyoneCanAddSelf": boolean,
>   "guestsCanInviteOthers": boolean,
>   "guestsCanModify": boolean,
>   "guestsCanSeeOtherGuests": boolean,
>   "privateCopy": boolean,
>   "locked": boolean,
>   "reminders": {
>     "useDefault": boolean,
>     "overrides": [
>       {
>         "method": string,
>         "minutes": integer
>       }
>     ]
>   },
>   "source": {
>     "url": string,
>     "title": string
>   },
>   "attachments": [
>     {
>       "fileUrl": string,
>       "title": string,
>       "mimeType": string,
>       "iconLink": string,
>       "fileId": string
>     }
>   ]
> }
> ```

You will find writable field `responseStatus`, which could have the possible values:

> - "needsAction" - The attendee has not responded to the invitation.
> - "declined" - The attendee has declined the invitation.
> - "tentative" - The attendee has tentatively accepted the invitation.
> - "accepted" - The attendee has accepted the invitation.